# Do all NextJS features work when dockerized and deployed to Cloud run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, next.js, cloud, middleware

Lets say for example I have a ***NextJS*** app with ***_middleware*** and ***getServerSideProps*** and ***getStaticProps*** and I want to use it on Cloud Run.
First using ***Docker*** I'll make an ***Image*** after that I upload it to a ***Cloud Run Containter***

Do I have to do some additional setup for everything to work properly?

For example do the pages with ***getStaticProps*** get automatically cached to a GCP cdn or do I have to setup that up separately and connect them somehow?

Will the pages with ***getServerSideProps*** be server side rendered?

And will all my ***_middleware*** work?

I've been digging in the Google cloud/Firebase documentation for a few days now and still find my self very confused.

I'm still fairly new to programming *(been on a self-learning journey for the past 6 months)* so please bare with me if these questions seem **foo**'lish..

Comment: Have you tested it? Could you share your experience with **_middleware** in Cloud Run? I used `dynamic routes`, `getStaticPaths`, `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` and all of them are working fine in Cloud Run.